# allocating memory with same identifier

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char *temp;
    while(1)
    {
        temp= malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
        /*some code*/
    }
}
```

My question is: I was allocating memory in every loop with same name. What will happen to previous memory allocated; and as we are creating  variables with same identifier why we are not getting any errors?

PS: Don't ask what I'm doing in this code. I was doing some other code and by mistake did it. Just re modified it and asking my problem .

Comment: So why in the first place are you allocating memory in each loop ? You can simply reuse the same memory block pointed to by temp in each loop.

Comment: suppose an char array contains 123 now next time i over write and put 5 it becomes 523 and if i use atof and add thes numbers i will get 646 instead of 128.....

Comment: sizeof(char) IS DEFINED AS 1.

Comment: For that problem of retaining old value, I have pointed to using `memset` to set the memory to 0, simply use `memset(temp, 0, 10)`. Here i have put 10 in the last argument as `sizeof(char)` is 1, but if you are using some other type's pointer use `memset(temp, 0, sizeof(<type>)*<length_of_array>)`

Comment: yea but earlier i didnt know about memset..otherwise i would have used it

Comment: @luther.....umm what???i know about that why u wrote that

Comment: void A(const std::string &s);             //1
    
     void a(std::string const& b);          //2
       const std::string &str() const       //3

--------------
is there any difference between 1 and two,and what does line 3 means????what happens when we add constant at the end of a function???

sry wasnt able to post this question thats why asking here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called a [memory leak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak). You have no way of ever freeing the memory, so it's lost to you.

Your process will keep growing in size until you run out of available memory (or, if it's 64 bit, swap the box into oblivion at which point your local sysadmin will come over and trounce you. If it's a production machine, you're likely to find out what a performance improvement plan is from your boss and HR.)

Answer (score 3):

> what will happen to prev memory allocated.

Will be lost forever. That is what is called "**[memory leak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak)**".

> and as we are creating variables with same identifier why we are not getting any errors

That's not a compilation error. The compiler doesn't follow your logic, only your syntax. Overwriting values is perfectly fine with the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

The previos memory allocated will be leaked, since its not freed and its address gets lost to the program. You don't get any errors because you are not creating variables with the same identifier, you are allocating different chunks of memory and storing the pointer to them into the same temp variable.

Consider reading some basic C programming material as you seem to be confusing variables with memory.

Comment: sry i wrote variables there,temp is identifier to pointer .........temp is a pointer whos pointing to the new memory allocated and as i am allocating new memory evrytime and storing its address in temp pointer...prev address is lost.... hmmm geesh thanx guys

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will in most cases not detect logical errors, such as this, where the programmer allocates memory but never frees it.

This is what we call a "memory leak".

Answer (score -1):

Here `temp` is a pointer not an identifier.
So `temp` POINTS to the memory allocated my `malloc`.

So when you allocate new memory and use the SAME pointer to point to the newly allocated memory, it NO LONGER points the the old allocated memory block and it is lost forever. So there you have a [memory leak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

If you no longer need the memory pointed to by temp after the end of the current iteration of the loop, use following code instead.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char *temp;
    while(1)
    {
        temp= malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
        /*some code*/

        /* free the memory pointed by temp */
        free(temp);
    }
}
```

This way you do not have a memory leak as the memory pointed to my temp is freed at the end of the iteration before a new block is allocated at the start of the next loop.

**Update:**
Also you can use the same memory block pointed to by temp throughout your loop. No need to reallocate in each iteration.
And if you do not want to retain any old memory you can simply use `memset`, like this

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    /* allocate memopry only once */
    char *temp = malloc(sizeof(char)*10);

    while(1){
        /* zero out the memory so no old data is left */
        memset((void*)temp, 0, sizeof(char)*10);

        /* some code that uses temp */
    }

    /* free the allocated memory */
    free(temp);
}
```

Comment: yup i did in the code ....actually by mistake i wrote memory allocate step outside if condition and got this problem

Comment: well yes, I was just emphasizing the point that temp only POINTS to the allocated memory. So why in the first place are you allocating memory in each loop ? You can simply reuse the same memory block pointed to by temp in each loop.

Comment: thanx for telling about memset()

Comment: why -1 for `sizeof`. I know `sizeof(char)` is 1 and you can simply use 10 here, but if you have some other datatype such as `int` or `long` this would allow you to use the same code you used in `malloc `in `memset`, and the OP may end up using this code in Some other place where he is using a pointer of different type, so its better to be safe.